# How to fix canvas grid for even number of cells?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I try to fill canvas rectangle or square by grid, but sometimes I get not even number or cells for canvas with sizes: 16px16px, but for 32x32px it works.

My attempts is by [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ktcphLx4/27/)

How to fix it?

```
  for (i = 0; i <= height; i += gridSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(1, i);
    ctx.lineTo(width, i);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= width; i += gridSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(i, height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

As you cans see I use `gridSize` as 4 is multiple of 32 or 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are setting the gridSize, so if you need even number of cells then the only option is to set the columns and rows to values that satisfy your needs, see code below.

```js
function CrossTemplate(gridOptions, canvas) {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = gridOptions.color;
  ctx.lineWidth = gridOptions.linesSize;
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);

  h = gridOptions.GridSize * gridOptions.rows +1
  w = gridOptions.GridSize * gridOptions.columns +1
  for (let i = 1; i <= h; i += gridOptions.GridSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(1, i);
    ctx.lineTo(w , i);    
  }    
  for (let i = 1; i <= w; i += gridOptions.GridSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 1);
    ctx.lineTo(i, h);    
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}


let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let gridOptions = {
  color: 'red',
  GridSize: 14,
  linesSize: 1,
  columns: 10,
  rows: 6
}

canvas.width = 5 + gridOptions.GridSize * gridOptions.columns;
canvas.height = 5 + gridOptions.GridSize * gridOptions.rows;
CrossTemplate(gridOptions, canvas);
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```